# Android NDK16 error ("operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'long long')"

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, clang++

In an attempt to transition from NDK 15c to NDK16b I've hit a roadblock compiling legacy code that is trying to write 64 bit long long values to ostream.

I've searched the NDK header files and it seems to me in `std/_ostream` that if `#ifdef _STLP_LONG_LONG` is defined then the ostream operator should support what I'm trying to do.

I fail to see what I need to do to enable this. I've tried defining that with -D_STLP_LONG_LONG to no avail.

My toolchain is using the clang compiler from the NDK.

Here is the actual compiler output:

```
MyInfo.cc:6499:33: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'long long')
      os << basename << ":" << (long long) val;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:104:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(unsigned char __x) { _M_put_char(__x); return *this; }
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:106:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(short __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:107:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(unsigned short __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:108:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(int __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:110:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(unsigned int __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:117:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(long __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:118:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(unsigned long __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:123:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(float __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:124:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(double __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:126:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(long double __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:130:10: note: candidate function
_Self& operator<<(bool __x);
     ^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:304:1: note: candidate function [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __os, char __c) {
^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:297:1: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, char __c) {
^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:311:1: note: candidate function [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __os, signed char __c) {
^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_ostream.h:318:1: note: candidate function [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __os, unsigned char __c) {
^
/Users/spartygw/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/stl/_iomanip.h:96:1: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
^
```

Comment: `_STLP_LONG_LONG` sounds like something from STLPort. Are you really using STLPort? If so, is there any reason why you can't use libc++ or gnustl instead?

Comment: @Michael you were right! The toolchain was built with stlport as the STL. I thought I was using libc++ (that's what I defined in Application.mk) but I missed that part in the toolchain creation. Please submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_STLP_LONG_LONG` is an [STLPort macro](http://www.stlport.com/doc/configure.html). If you really are using STLPort then you might have to edit the file `stl_mycomp.h` in the NDK.

However, since STLPort [only supports C++98](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) and is deprecated starting with NDK r16 you should use libc++ instead (prior to NDK r16 gnustl might also be an option).

Comment: This was indeed the issue, I built the toolchain with stlport by mistake